# Cmake fails with error: "Could not find compiler set in environment variable CC"

Tags: software-installation, compiling, gcc, g++, cmake

I am brand new to Linux/Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu two days ago to run ROSS (Rensselaer's Optimistic Simulation System) developed by Argonne National Lab. However, I have been running into some build/installation process with CMake I can't seem to figure out.

I issue the following terminal commands up until the point I get an error:

```
git clone http://github.com/carothersc/ROSS.git
cd ROSS
mkdir build
cd build
ARCH=x86_64 CC=mpicc CXX=mpicxx cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../install ../
```

After the 5th command I get the error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:57 (message):
  Could not find compiler set in environment variable CC:

  mpicc.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:1 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/lawrence/ROSS/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I have a feeling the solution to my problem is trivial but like I mentioned I'm brand new to Linux so I'd appreciate any help I can get and please go easy on me while describing the solution. Thanks!

Side Notes:

1. I installed CMake with:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install cmake & sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```
2. gcc and g++ is already installed

Comment: Your 5. command defines `CC=mpicc` ... Do you have mpicc installed?

Comment: I'm sure [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909432/installed-openmpi-library-but-cannot-use-mpicc-command-in-linux) will help you

Comment: Thanks Melebius and derHugo. I think the problem was my compilers couldn't be found so I issued the command: cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc and that seemed to work. Although I am now faced wih a new set of problems.